# Database of smartphone sensor data

Tags: machine-learning, accelerometer

I'm working on a machine learning project for classifying activity level (walking, running, sitting etc) based on smartphone accelerometer, gyroscope, and gps data

Of course I can just collect this data myself but this is very time consuming. I'm wondering if anybody knows of a database that contains this type of data, and importantly including labels for what type of activity they were doing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a dataset on the UCI Machine Learning repository. Check this [link](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Human+Activity+Recognition+Using+Smartphones) for the data and data description. There is no GPS information available.

The names for the relevant papers are there as well. So you can look those up if you want to.

Answer (score 4):

You can review this paper: [A Public Domain Dataset for Human Activity
Recognition Using Smartphones](https://www.elen.ucl.ac.be/Proceedings/esann/esannpdf/es2013-84.pdf)

In particular, tracking down the references leads to [this page containing the "Opportunity" activity data](http://www.opportunity-project.eu/challengedatasetdownload) and [this specific link to the data](http://www.opportunity-project.eu/system/files/Challenge/OpportunityChallengeLabeled.zip).